# How can I transpose axis in chart in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, linechart

I have a very simple table where I can easily plot the desired chart in Google Sheets:

[image]

When I pull this data in Google Data Studio and prepare a chart, then I get the results transposed.

Here is the outcome in Google Data Studio:

[image]

I want to make a chart where channels (dimensions) are displayed on X-Axis and the Metrics (is the sessions per week) is displayed on Y-Axis. As it is displayed in Google Sheets.

How can I achieve this? I tried to transpose, but couldn't find such option.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data format in you Google Sheet to look like the following:

[image]

You can then use week as your dimension, channel as the breakdown dimension and volume as the metric

[image]

Or transpose the data in sheets but you won't be able to do the transposing in Data Studio itself